# How to detect a sign change for elements in array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an array of numbers and the numbers change sign. I would like to find the index that there is sign change. How do I do that in Matlab? Is there any shortcut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering zero is a sign change from both a positive and negative number, you may use this -

```
%%// Given input
a = randi(10,1,12)-5

%%// Indices where sign change occurs
indices = find([0 diff(sign(a))]~=0)
```

Output -

```
a =

    -4     0    -3     5     3     1     0    -4     2    -4    -4     1


indices =

     2     3     4     7     8     9    10    12
```

Answer (score 2):

Operating along only one dimension

(eg for rows `dim=2`)

```
temp=diff(sign(Array),1,dim)
```

- `0` if signs were the same
- `-2` if it went from pos to neg
- `2` if it went from neg to pos
- `-1` if it went from pos to 0
- `1` if it went from neg to 0

so the indices of the sign changes can be given by the non zeros,

```
zeroCrossings=find(temp)
```

or for row and column indicies

```
[zC_row,zC_col]=find(temp)
```

notes: returns indices of elements immediately before a change